# Expose access and assignment operator from private vector

Tags: c++, vector, boost

I am working in a code in C++ where a class that I created stores a vector of boost/dynamic_bitset as a private field. I need to be able to access and modify any position in the vector to do bitset operations (&, |, ^, ...).

It's possible to expose the vector assignment (*=*) and access(*[]*) operators without having to reimplement them? Just like I did with iterators.

Here is the header:

```
class graph{
  typedef vector<boost::dynamic_bitset<>> tgraph;

  node person;
  tgraph gg;

 public:
  graph();
  graph(const uint person, const uint max_days, const uint max_nodes);

  void add_encounter_index(const node);
  void add_encounter_index(const node, const node, const node);

  void dump(ofstream& f, const vector<encounter>&);

  // iterators
  using iterator = tgraph::iterator;
  // using pointer = tgraph::value_type;
  using reference = tgraph::reference;
  // using value_type = tgraph::value_type;

  using const_iterator = tgraph::const_iterator;
  using const_reference = tgraph::const_reference;


  iterator begin() { return gg.begin(); }
  iterator end() { return gg.end(); }

  const_iterator begin() const { return gg.begin(); }
  const_iterator end() const { return gg.end(); }
  const_iterator cbegin() const { return gg.cbegin(); }
  const_iterator cend() const { return gg.cend(); }

};
```

Comment: You certainly could define `T& graph::operator[](size_t index) { return tgraph[index]; }`

Comment: Is that enough for assignment? I mean, with this I can do graph1[i] = dynamic_bitset<>(size)??

Comment: Yes, `graph1[i]` resolves to reference to the vector element, so you can do that. Overloading `operator=` would be for doing `graph1 = something;`  , you have to be careful there as it can get confusing to use when operator= does something other than the default behaviour (assigning from another graph, in this case)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overload `operator[]` for `graph` so that it resolves to a reference to the vector element, e.g.:

```
// Inline member function
auto& operator[](size_t index)
{
    return gg[i];
}
```

(In older versions of C++ you'll need to specify the `dynamic_bitset` type instead of `auto`).  This enables you to use:

```
graph1[i] = dynamic_bitset<>(size);
```

and other such statements.  You could overload `operator=`, but that applies to the usage `graph1 =`, and it can get confusing to overload this operator to do something different to its default behaviour. So if just the `operator[]` overload suits your requirements then I'd recommend just doing that one.